# Seeing a lot of pop up errors in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-7.0

Seeing a lot of pop up errors in Visual Studio 2022.
I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 - 17.3.5.
I am using .NET 7.0 (Preview) .NET 7.0.100-rc.1.22431.12.
Things don't really seem to work.
I have no idea what is happening.
I have tried to Update and Repair Visual Studio.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've found some older threads about this with previous versions of Visual Studio, and it seems an update to Visual Studio was the solution. But I assume you are already up to date - so it might have been reintroduced

Comment: @TimothyG. First I repaired, then I updated, as far as I remember. I am targeting the RC dotnet core 7.

Comment: You can also try using Visual Studio Preview https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Comment: @TimothyG. Ok I switched to Visual Studio Preview, so far I haven't seen the errors noted above. So I hope I am good. Thank you for you help.